# manage many ssh keys via ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent, keepassxc

I use keepassxc (my password manager) to manage my ssh keys. This means the keys are stored within the database (not stored on disk in a traditional way). When I unlock my password database, all keys are added to the agent. However, with a growing list of ssh keys, I get the problem that ssh tries all the keys in the agent, which results in `Too many authentication failures` if the remote host allows less authentication tries than i have ssh keys (and the particulary ssh key is far back in the list).

Is there a way to tell ssh: "for this host, use the key with fingerprint xyz, fetch it from the agent"? Alternatively pubkey xyz, but I can't use the `IdentityFile` option (and `IdentitiesOnly yes`), since I don't want to store my private keys on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I can't use the `IdentityFile` option (and `IdentitiesOnly yes`), since I don't want to store my private keys on disk.

You can. Store the corresponding *public* key(s) on disk. Use `IdentitiesOnly yes` and the `IdentityFile` option and point to the right public key. This solution is not explicitly explained in `man 5 ssh_config` where it describes `IdentityFile`, nevertheless it should work. It is mentioned in [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#i) where it describes `-i` [emphasis mine]:

> `-i identity_file`
> Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read. **You can also specify a public key file to use the corresponding private key that is loaded in `ssh-agent(1)` when the private key file is not present locally.**

Comment: This works, regardless of the value of `IdentitesOnly`. Thank you.