# ssh-agent with multiple keys

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, ssh-agent, ssh-config

I have a script which retrieves private keys from a repository database and adds them to the ssh-agent with `ssh-add - <<<"----My Private Key----"`

The keys don't get stored on the filesystem.
The problem is that I can only login with the first three added private keys. The keys 4 to 10 do not work because the remote servers have a limit set on failed login attempts which is 3.
Unfortunately I am not allowed to increase the limit of failed login attempts. Is there a way to tell ssh which agent-key to use apart from the `ssh -i <private key file>`

Comment: There's a recently added [destination constraint](https://www.openssh.com/agent-restrict.html) - you could see if your client supports it (I don't think it's necessary for the server to support it, except in the case of agent forwarding)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [manage many ssh keys via ssh-agent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/722139/manage-many-ssh-keys-via-ssh-agent)

Comment: The destination constraint is the solution Thanks to @steeldriver 
You may put your comment as solution. 
In order to add a key to the agent I managed to do this way:
`eval $(ssh-agent)`
`ssh-keyscan -t rsa myserver.domain > ~/.ssh/known_hosts`
`ssh-add -h myserver.domain - <<<"---PRIVATE KEY----"`